# Como atualizar as dependências do meu pacote sem precisar publicar uma nova versão do meu pacote?

Tags: npm

Eu estou desenvolvendo um pacote que tem como dependência outros pacotes.
O que queria saber é se existe uma forma do pacote que eu estou desenvolvendo já baixar a versão mais recente dos pacotes sem que eu precise atualizar a publicação no npm.

Por exemplo, digamos que eu tenha o pacote A 1.0 e o pacote B 1.0, meu pacote B depende do pacote A e o pacote A foi atualizado para a versão 1.1, existe uma forma de quando eu instalar o pacote B 1.0, ele puxar o pacote A 1.1? Ou eu preciso lançar um update do pacote B sempre que houverem atualizações nos pacotes que ele depende?

Comment: Se o pacote por seu, basta informar no *package.json* que você quer a versão mais recente (mesmo sabendo que isso pode quebrar sua aplicação) das dependências, usando *.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu exemplo onde o pacote `B@1.0` depende do pacote `A@1.0` o arquivo package.json do pacote `B` deve parecer com o seguinte:

```
{
  "name": "B",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "A": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Para pegar a última minor release do pacote `A@1.x.x` ao instalar o pacote `B@1.0` basta adicionar o prefixo `^` na versão:

```
{
  "name": "B",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "A": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Para pegar o último patch do pacote pacote `A@1.0.x` ao instalar o pacote `B@1.0` basta adicionar o prefixo `~` na versão:

```
{
  "name": "B",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "A": "~1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Caso queira pegar sempre a última versão do pacote `A` pasta utilizar o `latest` no lugar do número da versão (`"A": "latest"`).